# Laravel 5.1 Sync user to other users

Tags: laravel, synchronization, laravel-5.1

I build a Laravel app.
In table `users` I have 2 kinds of users - one user is restaurants and another user is restaurant stuff.

What I exactly need?

I want to sync user (res stuff) to user (restaurant). Is that possible or I need to move the restaurant to the other table and then sync?

I'm looking just for the idea and is that possible?

What is the difference between the user in the same table is `admin` field - res users have value '999' at `admin` column and res stuff has value '1' at `admin` column.

Comment: What do u mean by 'i want to sync use'

Comment: So you have the restaurant and restaurant staff and you want to relate staff to restaurants? Is that what you mean by syncing? Also the last part sounds like it's really specific to your system so you need to provide more details

Comment: Yes, i have restaurant and res stuff and I want to sync... but both is at the same table